# C++ vs Java/C# comparison

Tags: c#, java, c++

I found a [website](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/) comparing Java with C#][1](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/) in very details.
Does anybody know any website comparing c++ with Java or c++ with C# in the similar way?

Comment: Duplicate of a few questions: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+C%2B%2B+and+Java+differences&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=1db3655b1bbc91d8

Answer (score 3):

There are two big features/advantages that Java/C# have over C++:

1. `Built-in garbage collection/managed memory.`  You don't have to worry about cleaning up your objects.  Garbage collection is coming/available for C++ as well, but it's considerably less convenient to use.  Java/C# make it like the air you breath.  It hard to understate how much this can help your productivity and how much *enjoyment* this can add to your coding.
2. `The Well-organized built-in API/library.`  C++ probably has a much larger library available to it, if for no other reason than it's been around much longer and you can run it on my platforms, Java and C# are set apart by the amount of time, depth, and organization that went into the library that actually ships with the language.

On the other hand, Java/C# depend on an external runtime.  The lack of this dependency means that C/C++ are *everywhere*.   You can use C++ to program for almost any random esoteric platform out there, no matter what the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C_Sharp

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C++

I think that this is a pretty good comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well done comparison of C++/Java/C#/Objective-C in a tabular mode:

http://hyperpolyglot.org/cpp